# Proving the unique remainder theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation

Let $d∈\mathbb{Z}$, where $d \gt 0$ . Prove that for every $x ∈ \mathbb{Z}$ there is a unique remainder r ∈ $\mathbb{N}$ such that $x=qd+r$ where $q∈\mathbb{Z}$ and $0 \le r \lt d$.

Of course this is a very simple fact about remainders that we encounter early on in our math education. And it does seem intuitive, nevertheless I do have learn how to prove it, and how to do proofs in general. So far most of the 'proofs' I have done were actually verification than sophisticated proofs.

Now the proof is given as follows, and I put a number 1 next to the line I don't get.

To prove the uniqueness of r, assume $x=q_1d+r_1$ and $n=q_2d+r_2$, where $q_1$,$q_2$,$r_1$,$r_2$∈ $\mathbb{Z}$ and $0\le$ $r_1$, $r_2$ $\lt$ d.

Then $(q_1-q_2)d=r_2-r_1$

If $ r_1 \neq r_2$, we may assume $r_2 \gt r_1$.

This implies $r_2-r_1=md$, where $m\ge 1$ .

But this contradicts the fact that $r_2-r_1 \le r_2 \lt d$

To prove the existence of r, let $M=\{x-qd : q∈ \mathbb{Z}\}$

1. Then $ M ∩  \mathbb{N} \neq \varnothing $, I'm having trouble with this step.

and we let r be the first element in the subset M ∩ $\mathbb{N}$ of $\mathbb{N}$. Now r=x-qd for some q and we claim that $o \le r \lt d$. If $r \ge d$ then $r \gt r-d \ge 0$ and $r-d=x-(q+1)d ∈ M ∩  \mathbb{N}$. This contradicts that r is the first element in $ M ∩  \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Small error, you have $ 0 \le r_1,r_2 < d $

Comment: Where you wrote $0\le r_1,r_2\lt d$ you must have meant $0\le r\lt d.$

Comment: @bof Do you mean in the 11th line? Because the 2nd last line had that same inequality and I changed it.

Comment: @anna_xox Please don't change the question after answers have appeared. Now that you have deleted the numbered points (2) and (3) it makes Behrouz's answer appear not to address the question (in its current form),

Comment: @anna_xox No, I mean on the 4th line: "there is a unique remainder r ∈ $\mathbb{N}$ such that $x=qd+r$ where $q∈\mathbb{Z}$ and $0 \le r_1$, $r_2 \lt d$" does not make sense, but "there is a unique remainder r ∈ $\mathbb{N}$ such that $x=qd+r$ where $q∈\mathbb{Z}$ and $0 \le r \lt d$" does and is the correct statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your uniqueness, you so far only showed that $r_1=r_2$. You still need to (quickly) show that also $q_1=q_2$.

Regarding $M\cap\Bbb N\ne\emptyset$: If $x\ge 0$, then certainly $x-0\cdot d\in \Bbb N$. And if $x<0$, then $x-x\cdot d=(-x)\cdot (d-1)\in\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 1):

$$|dq_1-dq_2|=d\,|q_1-q_2|=|r_1-r_2|$$
we know $0\le r_1,r_2< d$, thus
$$d\,|q_1-q_2|=|r_1-r_2|<d$$
in other words
$$|q_1-q_2|<1$$

therefore  $q_1=q_2$ because $q_1,q_2\in Z$.

Comment: $ 0 \le r_1,r_2 < d $

Comment: It was typo. Thanks

Comment: Note to readers: the question has changed, but the OP asked about this part of the proof in a prior version of the question.